# How to make release Build for iOS using Phonegap Command Line Tools ?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap-build

I want to make the **Release Build** for **iOS platform** with the **Distribution Certificate** & **Mobile Provisioning Profile**. I want to do this using **Phonegap(Cordova) Command Line Tools** where I don't want to open **XCode**.

I have mobile provisioning profile and distribution certificate. I have also installed **XCode**, **NodeJS** on my machine but I don't want to open the Xcode only generate iOS release build using cordova command line tools.

If it is possible then please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PhoneGap how to make a release build from the command-line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660144/phonegap-how-to-make-a-release-build-from-the-command-line)

Comment: @Nirk : Above Question is not describing about How to add Distribution Certificate and Mobile Provisioning to the app.

Comment: Do it from the xcode. It will Make your life easier.

Answer (score 4):

```
cordova build ios --device --release
```

you should have a file called build.json in cordova.
In build.json, the content should like this

```
  "ios": {
    "debug": {
       "codeSignIdentitiy": "iPhone Development",
       "provisioningProfile": "*****"
    },
   "release": {
     "codeSignIdentitiy": "iPhone Distribution",
     "provisioningProfile": "******"
   }
 }
```

Comment: It took me a while to find out, that the provisioningProfile stars in your solution must be replaced with the mobileprovision file UUID and not with the mobileprovision filename itself. But now it works.

Comment: where should i place the build.json? just in the root? in the ios folder?

Comment: @Diceble Yes, the root.

Comment: "codeSignIdentitiy" ? isn't there a typo, because "codeSignIdentity" (without the surnumerous i at the end) seems more logical.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I had the same issue and my answer might help more people.

In your cordova/phonegap project, you can write to a build.xcconfig for all your configuration needs. The file is located here:  `<project-dir>/platforms/ios/cordova/build.xcconfig`

When your run `cordova build ios` with optional `--release` or `--device`, cordova will point to the file. This allows for easy configuration with minimal modification to cordova.

Answer (score 0):

Just run

`<project_dir>/platforms/ios/cordova/build.sh --release`

This `platforms/<platform>/cordova` dir contains actual build script. You can take a look at it to check out how cordova do builds.

**UPD.**
To make device build (i.e. with arm architecture, not for i386 emulator) pass `--device` parameter as well.

Answer (score -6):

You should go on build.phonegap.com and create there an account with an email and a password.
After, you login, there are steps:

```
1. Upload a zip of your project.
2. Start building it for first time.
3. Go on account (top left user icon) -> edit settings
4. Go to on Signing keys and add a new key by uploading the p12 and provisioning files
5. Unlock it using the password of the certificate.
6. Go on apps menu, you should have the app.
7. Press on app title in order to expand the builds
9. Select the key for IOS.

After that start a cmd window, make sure you have all requirements met (as is described here:http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html).
In that cmd window, you should perform following commands:
phonegap remote login -u <the account email> -p <the password>
phonegap remote build ios


In order to be all ok, you should be sure to have in config.json file the id of this new account.
Also, in order to perform the previous phonegap commands, you need to be in the folder of the project.

Please, be aware, the activation of the ios key is around 1 hour. If you want to do this automatically, you should first login, unlock the key, and build.
```

Comment: This post does not answer the question. The question is about building a release for IOS using the command-line tools. Not the Online-Build-Service.